# How do I toggle my button text as well as toggle the div

Tags: jquery, text, toggle

I feel as though this fairly simple and probably a common problem, but i need to change the text back to it original state on a second click,

```
        $('#about').hide();     
      $('#about-btn').click(function(){         
            $('#about').toggle('down'),
             $(this).text('close');


        });
```

It stays with the words closed and I need it to switch about when the element is toggled.

Comment: Shouldn't that comma after `.toggle('down')` be a semi-colon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#about-btn").click(function() {
    if (this.innerHTML === "close") {
        this.innerHTML = "open";
        $("#about").slideUp();
    } else {
        this.innerHTML = "close";
        $("#about").slideDown();
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pX4QW/

Comment: Thanks @vision new to the jquery world, can wait to help out others!